# Tidy up controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, service, repository, laravel-5

I'm setting up a Laravel 5.1 project and I've been making good progress with it but have run in to something that I'm struggling to figure out.

Basically, I have been creating objects to insert in to the database in my controller methods. This hasn't been too bad because they're usually one-liners.

However, I've run in to a more complex db entry and my controller has become a little muddied. Let me show you:

```
/**
 * Store a new ticket for the specified project.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @param  TicketsRequest $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store_ticket($id, TicketsRequest $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $project_id = $id;

    $project_tickets = Ticket::whereProjectId($id);
    $project_ticket_id = $project_tickets->count() + 1;

    $ticket = new Ticket;
    $ticket->user_id = $user_id;
    $ticket->project_id = $project_id;
    $ticket->project_ticket_id = $project_ticket_id;
    $ticket->title = $request->title;

    $ticket->save();

    $ticket_update = new TicketUpdate;

    $ticket_update->user_id = $user_id;
    $ticket_update->ticket_id = $ticket->id;
    $ticket_update->status_id = $request->status_id;
    $ticket_update->priority_id = $request->priority_id;
    $ticket_update->assigned_to = $request->assigned_to;
    $ticket_update->description = $request->description;

    $ticket_update->save();

    return redirect('/projects');
}
```

So as you can see, I'm creating a ticket which gets saved to the database, then also creating a ticket update which is also saved to the database.

What I'd like to do is extract this code in to 'something' to clean up my controller.

On my travels, I've found that maybe creating repositories might be the way forward. Otherwise I was thinking about some kind of service but I'm not really convinced that that is the way forward.

I have a subscription to Laracasts and found the following video but it's a little outdated and I was sure if this would still be the 'right' way to do this in Laravel 5.1 (I've found that things seem to have a natural home in 5.1 compared to older versions).

https://laracasts.com/lessons/repositories-simplified

Any suggestions/links etc would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate your objects often/always using the same set of attributes, you could easily extract that code into models constructors, e.g:

```
//in your model
public function __construct($user_id, $ticket_id, $request) {
  $this->user_id = $user_id;
  $this->ticket_id = $ticket_id;
  $this->status_id = $request->status_id;
  $this->priority_id = $request->priority_id;
  $this->assigned_to = $request->assigned_to;
  $this->description = $request->description;
}

// in your controller
$ticket_update = new TicketUpdate($user_id, $ticket->id, $request);
$ticket_update->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your implementation. I suggest you use `try catch` when calling the `save()` method in case something goes wrong and send a nice error to the user saying something like "something went wrong, contact your admin".